# Snap.svg with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, snap.svg

I'm trying to use Snap.svg in my Vue.js app, however I'm confuse with how to do so.
I used Vue CLI 3 command to initialized my project, and install the snapsvg dependency with yarn.

Also, I read [this article.](https://jamesscheller.com/adding-snap-svg-to-vue-js-and-nuxt-js-projects/)
But I can't find the `webpack.base.conf.js` file !

When I try to import the dependency into my main.js file or into any component I've got no error but my App become empty.

What did I miss to properly import Snap.svg in my Vue.js app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vue cli 3, webpack is configured in vue.config.js

To use snap place the vue.config.js with the following content in your root directory

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule("snapsvg")
      .test(require.resolve("snapsvg"))
      .use("imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0")
      .loader("imports-loader")
      .end();
  }
};
```

add this line to your main.js file:

```
const snap = require(`imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js`);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hacking webpack, 
use [snapsvg-cjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapsvg-cjs)

> This project simply unwraps the excellent SnapSVG from its published AMD format and hosts it on NPM as CommonJS in a package called snapsvg-cjs. This package then works out-of-the-box with Webpack, without needing any import-loader hax.

```
npm install snapsvg-cjs;
```

the only line of code you'll need:

```
import "snapsvg-cjs";
```

Comment: So that your linter does not complain when using Snap on the components, import it like this: `import * as Snap from 'snapsvg-cjs'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on any of your Vue components

Run: `npm install snapsvg-cjs`

```
<template>
  <!-- Important that HTML element should be an SVG tag -->
  <svg id="chart"></svg>

</template>

<script>
import * as Snap from 'snapsvg-cjs'

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.drawChart();
  },
  methods: {
    drawChart() {

     var s = Snap('#chart');

     s.rect(0,0, 100, 100)
     
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
  #chart {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
```